# Mongodb: What does webscale means?

Tags: scalability, mongodb

Mongodb is known to be webscale. I tried looking on the internet about what webscale actually means but ends with no luck. So, what does webscale really means? And how is it any different than any other scale? And why is mongodb known to be webscale while other DB is not?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you referring to this parody - http://mongodb-is-web-scale.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

I have feeling this is a term they've coined themselves. I'm assuming that it alludes to the fact that MongoDB supports sharding natively, which allows it to split a database (and requests) over several machines automatically, without this functionality having to be coded into the application itself. In fact, one of MongoDB's main strengths over MySQL is the ease of scaling.

Answer (score 0):

http://community.oclc.org/engineering/2009/05/what-is-web-scale.html

But it was really coined here about mongodb

http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1016320617/mongodb-is-web-scale

Comment: The first link is dead. Here is a backup by Wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20120415092552/http://community.oclc.org/engineering/2009/05/what-is-web-scale.html